# JSON TO C# Deserializing

Tags: c#, api, http, json-deserialization, csharpcodeprovider

Can someone help me deserialize JSON from this api https://www.freeforexapi.com/api/live?pairs=EURUSD,GBPUSD to a C# Object? I have tried many ways and examples I found online, non seems to be working

Comment: What problems are you having? Please show details, like an example of the JSON produced and the C# classes that you are trying to deserialize into.

Comment: Please site the examples that you have tried, and the errors you encountered when they did not work.

Comment: This is the JSON I get : {"rates":{"EURUSD":{"rate":1.175883,"timestamp":1601901665}},"code":200} And I would like to deserialize the rate, timestamp and the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here rates is Map, So Response C# class look like this:

```
public class Response
{
    public Dictionary<string, Rate> Rates{get;set;}
    public int Code {get;set;} 
}

public class Rate
{
    public double Rate { get; set; }
    public long TimeStamp { get; set; }

}
```

To deserialize :

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(jsonObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

for example, using newtonsoft json
create class for response

```
public class EURUSD    {
    public double rate { get; set; } 
    public int timestamp { get; set; } 
}

public class GBPUSD    {
    public double rate { get; set; } 
    public int timestamp { get; set; } 
}

public class Rates    {
    public EURUSD EURUSD { get; set; } 
    public GBPUSD GBPUSD { get; set; } 
}

public class Root    {
    public Rates rates { get; set; } 
    public int code { get; set; } 
}
```

and then deserialize response, like

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
```

you may use json2csharp website to easy generate classes like this^